# I have weekly satellite data, but I want to convert it to monthly data. How would I do that?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter

I have weekly satellite data and I want to convert it to monthly data, where it's months, longitude, and latitude from 1993 (january) - 2019 (december).

I originally made a for loop to just take the mean of every 4 weeks to get the monthly means:

```
sss_md_monthly = []

weeks = sss_md.time.size//4 
for i in range(weeks):   
    sss_md_monthly.append(np.mean(sss_md[i::4],axis=0))
    
sss_md_monthly = np.array(sss_md_monthly)
```

However, I noticed that there are leap years and particular months that have 5 weeks instead of 4 weeks per month, so my for loop to get the monthly means is not correct since I am taking the means of every 4 weeks (one month), but some months may have 5 weeks instead of 4.

```
time = np.array(sss_md.time) #making time array

for i in range(int(len(time)/4)):
    print(time[i*4:(i+1)*4]) # printing the time step for every 4 weeks 

['1993-01-06T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-01-13T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-01-20T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-01-27T12:00:00.000000000'] #all of january 1993
['1993-02-03T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-02-10T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-02-17T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-02-24T12:00:00.000000000'] # all of february 1993
['1993-03-03T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-03-10T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-03-17T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-03-24T12:00:00.000000000'] # MARCH 1993 has 5 weeks instead of 4
['1993-03-31T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-04-07T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-04-14T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-04-21T12:00:00.000000000']
['1993-04-28T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-05-05T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-05-12T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-05-19T12:00:00.000000000']
['1993-05-26T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-06-02T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-06-09T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-06-16T12:00:00.000000000']
['1993-06-23T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-06-30T12:00:00.000000000'
 '1993-07-07T12:00:00.000000000' '1993-07-14T12:00:00.000000000']
....
```

How would I convert weekly data into the proper monthly time series when there are leap years or certain months with more weeks than others?

Someone kindly suggested this:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(n[:10],"%Y-%m-%d") for n in time] # time = np.array(sss_md.time)

month, year = time[0].month, time[0].year
group_month = {}
for i in time:
    if (i.month, i.year) in group_month:
       group_month[(i.month, i.year)].append(i)
    else:
       group_month[(i.month, i.year)] = i
print(group_month)
```

However I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-cb22eada7b48> in <module>
      2 from datetime import datetime as dt
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(n[:10],"%Y-%m-%d") for n in time]
      5 
      6 month, year = time[0].month, time[0].year

<ipython-input-178-cb22eada7b48> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 from datetime import datetime as dt
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(n[:10],"%Y-%m-%d") for n in time]
      5 
      6 month, year = time[0].month, time[0].year

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Is this error from the structure of my time variable?

Comment: Try printing `[n for n in time]` looks like n is not a string in your case.

Comment: edited my answer to convert generator expressions to strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have to convert the time to a datetime object and then compare and group it.

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
time = [datetime.strptime(str(n)[:10],"%Y-%m-%d") for n in np.array(sss_md.time)]

month, year = time[0].month, time[0].year
group_month = {}
for i in time:
    if (i.month, i.year) in group_month:
       group_month[(i.month, i.year)].append(i)
    else:
       group_month[(i.month, i.year)] = [i]
print(group_month)
```

You can use datetime.strfttime to convert values back to the old format.

Note that I am using `n[:10]` in the list comprehension to make our formating easier since your sample times have a lot of repeating values.

Comment: Thank you! this is really close. I converted my time series to the proper year - month - day, so that is fine. but now I get this error: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of strings which looks like this:

```
dates = (
    "1993-01-06T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-01-13T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-01-20T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-01-27T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-02-03T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-02-10T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-02-17T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-02-24T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-03-03T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-03-10T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-03-17T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-03-24T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-03-31T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-04-07T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-04-14T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-04-21T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-04-28T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-05-05T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-05-12T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-05-19T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-05-26T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-06-02T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-06-09T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-06-16T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-06-23T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-06-30T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-07-07T12:00:00.000000000",
    "1993-07-14T12:00:00.000000000"
)
```

Then you can group the strings by year and month using `itertools.groupby` and a custom key. This assumes that the strings will already be in sorted order, according to year and month.

```
from itertools import groupby

def key(string):
    return string.split("-")[:2]

month_groups = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(dates, key=key)]
print(month_groups)
```

You could make the `key` grouping function even cuter by, instead of splitting on `"-"`, parse each string and turn it into a `datetime.datetime` object. Then return the datetime object's year and month attributes.